# How do I make this happen when I do a function and put the parameters?

Tags: javascript

```
function[function name](parameters){
  console.log(string attached to parameter, string attached to parameter, parameter) and print)
}
```

Now what I have is this:

[image: What I have]

Perform the task I want to do in the function.

Comment: Your question is not readable. Please use a code block, not an image of code.

Comment: You have a random semicolon in the wrong place

Comment: `{b}$` is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a semicolon which doesn't have to be there, second, string interpolations follow the format `${variableName}`, not `{variableName}$`, so you need to change your function to :

```js
function fcuadratica (a, b, c) {
  console.log(`x² ${a}, ${b} x`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you are trying to achieve but this shows one way of formatting a template string to make it look like a quadratic equation.

```js
function fcuadratica (a, b, c) {
  console.log(`${a}x² + ${b}x + ${c} = 0`)
}

fcuadratica(3, 4, 2);
```